# Creating dynamic legends in R/leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I am wondering if there is a way to create dynamic legends based off the values in a specific column. For example looping through the Items$color category and listing Green, Orange and Red with their respective icons/color inside the legend square.

Sample Code:

```
Items <- structure(list(name = c("batteries", "bracelet", "jar", "coffee ", 
                                     "magazine", "book"), color = c("red", "green", "orange", "green", 
                                                                    "orange", "orange"), lat = c(41.61238, 46.18012, 45.73361, -51.35723, 
                                                                                                 -5.25024, 16.54793), long = c(-153.0564, 153.0042, -82.22083, 
                                                                                                                               71.63157, -53.44893, 48.57037)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    -6L))
 
icons <- awesomeIcons(icon = "fa-dollar",
                              lib = 'fa',
                              iconColor = "black",
                              markerColor = Items$color)
Items %>%
          leaflet() %>%
          addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
          #Add Markers
          addAwesomeMarkers(lng = ~long,
                            lat = ~lat,
                            icon=icons,
                            label = Items$color)
```

Side Question, I am trying to [use this icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/hand-holding-dollar?s=solid&f=classic) but for some reason writing `"hand-holding-dollar"` in the icon field does not work. Do I need to install a package for extra icons?

Appreciate any reference links or pointers!

Thanks

Comment: [Check out this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/10/awesome-marker-legends-in-leaflet/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to create a dynamic legend with the following code :

```
library(leaflet)

Items <- structure(list(name = c("batteries", "bracelet", "jar", "coffee ", "magazine", "book"), 
                        color = c("red", "green", "orange", "green", "orange", "orange"),
                        lat = c(41.61238, 46.18012, 45.73361, -51.35723,  -5.25024, 16.54793),
                        long = c(-153.0564, 153.0042, -82.22083, 71.63157, -53.44893, 48.57037)),
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

icons <- awesomeIcons(icon = "fa-dollar",
                      lib = 'fa',
                      iconColor = "black",
                      markerColor = Items$color)

(Items %>% leaflet()

       %>% addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap")

       %>% addAwesomeMarkers(lng = ~long,
                             lat = ~lat,
                             icon = icons,
                             label = Items$color,
                             group = Items$color)

       %>% addLegend(values = unique(Items$color),
                     group = unique(Items$color), 
                     position = "topright",
                     labels = unique(Items$color), 
                     colors =  unique(Items$color))

       %>% addLayersControl(overlayGroups = unique(Items$color),
                            options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, quick question, which parameter is responsible to make the markers appear and disappear? I tried it on my data set and the legend appeared but the check boxes weren't working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is "addAwesomeMarkers".